# How to get row with last day of month in Sql Server query

Tags: sql-server

Given a table with a single row for each day of the month, how can I query it to get the row for the last day of each month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adapting the following query. The `SELECT` statement within the `IN` clause choses the dates for the outer query to return.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE DateColumn IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(DateColumn)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY YEAR(Datecolumn), MONTH(DateColumn)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from your table where the `YourDateColumn` field of the record equals the last date of the month `YourDateColumn` belongs to:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0, YourDateColumn )+1,0)) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of below query:

```
    DECLARE @Dates Table (ID INT, dt DATE)
    INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES
    (1,'2017-02-01'),
    (2,'2017-02-03'),
    (3,'2017-02-04'),
    (4,'2017-03-03'),
    (5,'2017-04-03'),
    (6,'2017-04-04')

    SELECT MAX(dt) AS LastDay FROM @Dates GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,dt)
```

OUTPUT

```
LastDay
2017-02-04
2017-03-03
2017-04-04
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,dt) AS [MONTH],MAX(DATEPART(DAY,dt)) AS LastDay FROM @Dates GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,dt)

MONTH   LastDay
   2    4
   3    3
   4    4
```

Comment: That works if the row only contains a date value.  Sorry for not being clear but in my case, each row will not only have a date but also additional columns.  So as soon as I include one of those columns in the query and group by I end up getting a row for every day of the month.